# Mongoose Failing to connect to MongoDB replicaSet

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a replicaSet running in k8s, while trying to connect to the replicaSet from nodejs using mongoose, the connection fails with this logs:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connection timed out                                                                                                                              
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:807:32)                                                                                
    at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:340:10                                                                                                                           
    at promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:10:12)                                                                                    
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1140:10)                                                                                            
    at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:339:20)                                                                                                        
    at /app/src/connect.ts:21:14                                                                                                                                                
    at Promise._execute (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:313:9)                                                                                          
    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:488:18)                                                                                   
    at new Promise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:79:10)                                                                                                     
    at connect (/app/src/connect.ts:20:10)                                                                                                                                      
    at initialiseDatabase (/app/src/connect.ts:8:5)                                                                                                                             
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/mongoose.ts:36:19)                                                                                                                          
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)                                                                                                                 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)                                                                                                   
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)                                                                                                                      
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/user/operations/find-by-id.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/middleware/authenticate.ts:7:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/app.ts:8:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'mongodb-0.mongodb-headless.staging.svc.cluster.local:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'mongodb-1.mongodb-headless.staging.svc.cluster.local:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'mongodb-2.mongodb-headless.staging.svc.cluster.local:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
```

And this is my connection string:

```
mongodb://username:pw@mongodb-0.mongodb-headless.staging.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongodb-1.mongodb-headless.staging.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongodb-2.mongodb-headless.staging.svc.cluster.local:27017/labxpert?authSource=admin&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=50000&replicaSet=rs0
```

When I test the connection with the mongo Shell, it works just fine.

What could be causing the `MongooseServerSelectionError: connection timed out`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may face this problem with mongoose `v6+` and `nodejs` and white listing your ip has not solved it or changing from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.

**Solution**
Set the following options for the mongoose client connection options:

```
     mongoose.connect(url, { 
                            maxIdleTimeMS: 80000,
                            serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 80000,
                            socketTimeoutMS: 0,
                            connectTimeoutMS: 0
                            }
```

These options stop the mongoose client from timining out the connection before it selects a primary from the DB cluster.

Please remember to set any other options relevant to your setup like if you are running a cluster, make sure to set the `replicaSet` option or if you have authentication enabled, set the `authSource` option or the database you are connecting to `dbName`.

Some of these options can be set in the connection string.

The full list of options can be found here: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.2/interfaces/MongoClientOptions.html#authSource